# Checking for nil produces false even though object is nil

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, lldb

Working on a tableview who has cells build in IB. The cells use some custom UITextFields. The UITextFields have an optional UIImage property that should be nil when the controller loads.

I'm doing a check for nil and it keeps producing false, even though the object is nil.

```
(lldb) po icon
nil

(lldb) po icon == nil
false
```

What's interesting is for primitive types in the same textField, I get the expected behavior.

```
(lldb) po icon4
nil

(lldb) po icon4 == nil
true
```

I'm evaluating at the Texfields init, so there's now much else happening in this textfield.

Is there anything obvious here I'm missing?

Comment: cells are reused

Comment: Not sure what you’re trying to get at in this context. I would expect cell properties that are nil to evaluate true to == nil. Are you saying this is expected?

Comment: What does `p icon` (or `frame var icon`) say in the case where "icon == nil" is returning false?  `po` asks the object to describe itself by sending it the `description` message and printing the resultant string, it doesn't tell you what the pointer itself is.  If `p icon` is 0x0 and `p icon == nil` returns false, that is unexpected, and if you can reproduce the behavior please file a bug with a reproducer with http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Thanks @JimIngham p icon does return a value, so I guess it is pointing to something.. Here is what I see: `(lldb) p icon
(UIImage?) $R0 = nil
(lldb) po icon
nil

(lldb) po icon == nil
false

(lldb) p icon == nil
(Bool) $R10 = false`

Comment: Optionals are a little odd: they are not pointers that can be 0x0 or not, they are actually a swift generic enum with two possible values "none" which translates to nil, and "some" whose associated data is the object they contain.  You can see this, for instance, if you do `frame variable --raw icon`.  So everybody who is printing this (except for `--raw`) is coloring the truth a bit.  That said, I can't get an optional with value of "none" to return "false" to `p icon == nil`.  That is unexpected.  If you can repro this please file a bug.